# PHP get constructor argument values from ReflectionClass

Tags: php, reflection

Is there a way to get the values that were used to instantiate a class from a Reflection (or any other way)?

```
class MyClass
{
  public function __construct($one, $two)
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

```
$instance = new MyClass(1, 2);

$reflection = new ReflectionClass($instance);

// get the values of "$one" and "$two" that were used to initialise the class
// (without having them as properties with getters or readonly).
```

Ideally to be able to access the arguments with their original values as such:

```
[
  'one' => 1,
  'two' => 2
]
```

The use-case is to be able to compare an instance of the class and its constructor arguments with a mock of its kind and its expected constructor arguments' values.

Simply put, to be able to determine whether the instance was initialised with the same values as the ones expected in the test, the challenge is that it should be done post-initialisation. The use of `Mockery` and other PHPUnit magic is also possible.

Comment: How should reflection be able to distinguish how these values were set? The given example does not show what you mean by "original values"

Comment: As the name implies ReflectionClass is about classes, that you can give it an object is basically just a shortcut for `new ReflectionClass(get_class($instance));` it doesn't give any information about object instances. You could use Reflection to get the properties of the class and then check their values on the actual object. Alternatively you could look at json_encode and get the required result that way.

Comment: @ChristianM that works only if every constructor argument is a property in the class and their values are preserved (i.e. set as-is). I need this for testing purposes where I can compare an instantiated instance's constructor arguments with a mock's constructor expectations.

Comment: If I understand right what you want there is no way to do that. Could you show some pseudo code as to what the test is supposed to do? I have a feeling there is something amiss.

Comment: @mulkave as said before I doubt there is an answer to this, if possible you could use  a mock instead of that class to check if the values are being set int he constructor, but otherwise I would find it a much more resiliant test if you were testing some outcome of those constructor variables, because if they are not available as properties to the outside it should not matter to you if they were set correctly but only if the resulting object behaves as expected.